# CountdownCircleTimer duration time is not updated in the next question

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a quiz app in React, and now I am working on a timer for the answer user. I am using CountdownCircleTimer (https://github.com/vydimitrov/react-countdown-circle-timer#props-for-both-reactreact-native). I set the time duration for this timer first correctly, but for the next question is still using the first time, what set on the start. In console.log I see a new set time. Can you explain to me, why?

First lines I define:

```
const [time, setTime] = useState(-1);
```

Then I set the first time:

```
if(time === -1){
      setTime(questionBankOfEvent[0].timeLimit);         
}
```

And then in return():

```
<CountdownCircleTimer
  onComplete={() => {
    handleAnswerOptionClick(
      false,
      questionBankOfEvent[currentQuestion].pointsForQuestion
    );
    setTime(questionBankOfEvent[currentQuestion + 1].timeLimit);
    return [true];
  }}
  isPlaying
  duration={time}
  colors={[["#004777", 0.33], ["#F7B801", 0.33], ["#A30000"]]}
>
  {renderTime}
</CountdownCircleTimer>;
```

renderTime:

```
const renderTime = ({ remainingTime }) => {
  if (remainingTime === 0) {
    return <div className="timer">Too late...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <div className="timer">
      <div className="text">Remaining</div>
      <div className="value">{remainingTime}</div>
      <div className="text">seconds</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: would you please add Codepen sample and tell more about the expected output

Comment: Sorry, it would be hard, because I have fetching data from DB, importing many files. But I found a solution for my problem, I gave the answer for my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer on my own question :-) because I found a solution to this problem. If you want to have CountdownCircleTimer with dynamicly change duration, you need key ... more you can find here: https://github.com/vydimitrov/react-countdown-circle-timer/discussions/73